# Flutter Wrap widget align: left inside ExpansionPanel

Tags: flutter, widget, alignment

This is strange, the Wrap widget, containing FilterChips, is centering inside it's parent a ExpansionPanel.  I've tried wrapping the Wrap Widget in a Flexible widget, no reaction, I've tried wrapping in an Expanded widget, no reaction.

There doesn't appear to be a property on the Expansion panel to left align body: Widgets. It's important because some of the ExpansionPanels are aligning to the left, when the Wrap widget has been forced to full width, but others, like pictured, center.  Ultimately I'm going to wrap all the children widgets in the ExpansionPanel in a Padding widget, but I need the child Wrap widgets aligning left first.

```
bool travelSack;
ExpansionPanelRadio backpackingPanel = ExpansionPanelRadio(
            value: "Backpacking",
            headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: FaIcon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.globeEurope,
                  size: 19,
                ),
                title: Text("Backpacking"),
              );
            },
            body: Expanded(child:
            Wrap(spacing: 4, children: [
              FilterChip(
                showCheckmark: false,
                label: Text('Travel rucksack'),
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: travelSack ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                ),
                selected: travelSack,
                onSelected: (bool selected) {
                  setState(() {
                    travelSack = !travelSack;
                  });
                },
                selectedColor: Colors.green.shade500,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade500,
              ),
        ])
    );
```

I'm Scoobied, help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I solved this by nesting the Wrap widget inside an Align widget:

```
 Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft, 
child: Wrap(....
```

I do not like my solution, I'm wary of so much nestings effect on performance and sprawling code harms legibility, so if you have a better solution I'm all eyes. x Sam.

Comment: Agreed. This should be achievable with a property, like row or column.

Answer (score 19):

`Wrap` has an `alignment` property that you can use to align the children.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap/Wrap.html

```dart
Wrap(
  ...
  alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  children: [],
),
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and resolve with SizedBox:

```dart
ExpansionPanelRadio backpackingPanel = ExpansionPanelRadio(
  value: "Backpacking",
  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {},
  body: SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity, // Use when direction: Axis.horizontal
    height: double.infinity, // Use when direction: Axis.vertical
    child: Wrap(
      spacing: 4,
      children: [
        FilterChip(
          showCheckmark: false,
          label: Text('Travel rucksack'),
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: travelSack ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          ),
          selected: travelSack,
          onSelected: (bool selected) {
            setState(() {
              travelSack = !travelSack;
            });
          },
          selectedColor: Colors.green.shade500,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade500,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Remember to not use width and height SizedBox property at same time, only one for each Wrap.direction.

[Reference](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14006#issuecomment-616648576)

Answer (score 1):

You can align the widget to the left with property of .start like this.

```
Wrap(alignment: WrapAlignment.start,)
```

// You can also use the
direction:Axis.horizontal property to align according to your needs.